# How do you add a (hyper)link to an HTML variable in a for loop? (Flask)

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I'm using Spotify's API to list all the playlists I have on a local server. When you enter a Spotify song link in the input box, you select a playlist and the song gets added after clicking "submit song." I have been able to display each playlist and its respective follower count using a dictionary with the names of each playlist (as the keys) and the respective follower count (as the values). Here is a picture of what the webpage looks like (behind the red blocks is the rest of the abbreviated name and the follower count). [image]

For the next step, I would like to hyperlink the displayed text to the playlist link so that if you click on the name of a playlist, it opens in a new tab. I started by creating a dictionary of the playlist names (keys) and corresponding links (values) but am unsure of how to incorporate this in my HTML file. I am using a for-loop in my HTML page to generate each radio button (shown below). Here is the code to the Flask main.py (the other imported files are just small functions working with the API):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import parse, user_add_to_playlist, load_playlist, playlist_links

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    output = ""
    playlist = "Enter a song, select a playlist, and click 'Submit Song' to add it"
    playlists_dict = playlist_links.playlist_links_dict.items()


    playlists_followers_dict = load_playlist.load_playlist()
    # plist_links = playlist_links.playlist_links_dict.items()

    if request.method == "POST":
        song_link = request.form['song-link']
        song_uri = parse.parse_uri(song_link)
        playlist = request.form['playlist']
        playlist_id = parse.parse_playlist(playlist)
        song_name = user_add_to_playlist.add_song(song_uri, playlist_id)
        output = f"Thank you for sharing { song_name }!"

    return render_template('index.html', playlists_followers_dict=playlists_followers_dict, output=output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port = 1234)
```

Here is the index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="banner">
        <h1>Spotify API Test</h1>
        <br>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Spotify Link:
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="song-link" size = "100"></input>
        <br>
        <br>
      </form>
      {% for key, value in playlists_followers_dict.items() %}
      <input type="radio" name="playlist" value="{{ key }}"> {{ key }}, {{ value }} Followers<br>
      {% endfor %}
      <br>
      <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Song"></input>
      </form>  
      <div id="output"></div>
      <p class="output-statement">{{output}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I alter this for loop in my HTML to have each playlist linked with the values from the plist_links dictionary so that they open in a new tab when you click the name?

```
{% for key, value in playlists_followers_dict.items() %}
<input type="radio" name="playlist" value="{{ key }}"> {{ key }}, {{ value }} Followers<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further experimenting this is how I solved it:

Instead of using two dictionaries (one with playlist name and follower count, the other with playlist name and link), I created a list of tuples which I stored in a variable called 'playlists' that looked printed like this:

[('Chill...', '1', 'https://example.com), (House..., 0, 'https://example.com), ..., ..., ...]

Then in my HTML I changed my loop to the following:

```
{% for (name, follower_count, link) in playlists: %}
  <input type="radio" name="playlist" value="{{name}}"><a href={{link}} target="_blank">{{name}}, {{follower_count}} Followers</a><br>
{% endfor %}
```